# Sometimes it gives output and sometimes index error

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using this code to print the last link of the page in tabs,when i have run this code early this morning it was printing the last link,but now when i have tried to run it is showing an index error 
here is my code

```
#parsing the url
import urllib2, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

site= "http://www.doctoralia.com.au/healthpros"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
last_page = soup.select('ul.pager li.last a')[0]
print last_page
```

Comment: Show the error as well please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just an anti-web-crawling technique. I've put your code in a `while True` loop and got the error in a minute. Then, if you open up a page in a web-browser, you would see a captcha check and a message:

> Abuse detected
>
> Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network.

My guess is that you were hitting the site too frequently. Besides, the site provides an [API](https://developer.doctoralia.com/), consider using it instead of web-scraping it's HTML pages.

Hope that helps.